# slicing assignment with negative index

Tags: variable-assignment, slice

I am having some problems regarding slicing assignment:

As i understand that general syntax of slicing is l[start:stop:step]

when we use positive step then we transverse forward and when we use negative step we transverse backward:

l=[1,2,3,4]

l[3:1:1]=[5]

when i use the above assignment then it inserts the element 5 at the index  3 like insert operation
but when i use
l[-3:-1:-1]=[5]
then it shows me value error....
i m totally confused..
please explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking about slices in *Python*,
the 'step' part will make the slice an *extended* slice.

Assigning to extended slices is only possible if the list on the right
hand side is of the same size as the extended slice.
see
https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html

So the confusing thing actually is that your `l[3:1:1] = [5]` does ***not*** raise
a ValueError, because the left and right size differ (0 and 1; note
that both your `l[3:1:1]` and `l[-3:-1:-1]` evaluate to empty lists).

I think that can be explained by the fact that a step of 1 is no different
from the original slice syntax `[start:end]`, and may therefore be handled
as a normal slice.

If your goal is inserting, just don't use the step.